# Where can I find a C# class for "Shamir's Secret Sharing"?

Tags: c#, .net, security

I am trying to find a class or something that would allow me to do [Shamir's Secret Sharing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shamir%27s_Secret_Sharing).

I found a program in C# that allows you to do it but it does not supply source code. I was just wondering if anyone has a class that already does what I need.

Comment: added the "homework" tag, since it sounds like it may be homework.

Comment: @Dana: Are you going to provide justification for undoing my valid edits?

Comment: @Rich B: Actually revision 4 is the best of the bunch, because "wandering" is a completely different word than "wondering". Your edits didn't really help that much.

Comment: Addendum: actually Dana didn't really undo any edits, just changed the title along with a bunch of other edits.

Comment: So apparently nobody else thinks this is homework?

Comment: @GregD: I don't really think it is, nor does it matter.

Comment: I don't think that it is clearly homework.

Comment: No, but I'd totally tag that 'plzsendtehcodez'.

Comment: And if it is homework, shouldn't a vote to close be cast instead of a retagging? (That is if you have such rep.)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/230510/homework-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Just because it's homework doesn't mean it is to be closed. Try reading the FAQ for once.

Comment: Confused about homework?: "It is okay to ask about homework. For one, it would be impossible to stop it all even if we wanted to. StackOverflow exists to help programmers learn and provide a standard repository for programming problems, both simple and complex, and this includes helping students."

Comment: Sounds to me like he just doesn't want to reinvent the wheel. Kudos for that!

Comment: It's a split subject, fair enough.

Comment: @RichB It may not matter to you, but it matters to me if a question is tagged as homework.  This is a collaborative effort right, or where you made supreme overlord of editing while nobody was looking?

Comment: @GregD: Why the hostility? I just don't care if you put it in or not. I don't think it is, and I don't see the point in the tag, but I am not going (and have made no attempts) to stop you from doing it.

Comment: @GregD: I think we should save the homework tag for questions where we are reasonably sure it's someone's homework. In this case, I'm not reasonably sure.

Comment: @Gortok - Fair enough.  Much nicer way of putting it as opposed to "nor does it matter" approach.

Comment: @GregD: You assume a lot on my words. How do you know I didn't mean that I don't agree, nor does it matter what I think?

Comment: @RichB - Same as you assuming I was being hostile based on my words I guess.  It is what it is.  Truce?

Comment: @GregD: No feelings of malice either way, but calling me the 'supreme overlord of editing' does have a way of sounding hostile. It is all behind us now though.

Comment: a little late to the game on this but i'm 29 and just doing this for fun I haven't had homework in quiet some time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: As noted in comments, this project doesn't actually have C# source code - but I can't delete the answer now as it's been accepted. Perhaps the OP was actually content to use a wrapper after all.

[SecretSharp](http://sourceforge.net/projects/secretsharp/) (linked from the wikipedia article) is GPL - you can [browse the code here](http://secretsharp.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/secretsharp/).

Comment: This is a highly misleading project. Looks like a good hit at first, but in fact it's a GUI wrapper around a C++ interface library around Crypto++. I certainly cannot find anything remotely like an actual implementation of Shamir's Secret Sharing in C#.

Comment: I looked at the source and @romkyns is right, there is no C# implementation of the requested algorithm there. I wonder why the OP marked it as the accepted answer since it doesn’t provide the code asked for the in question...??

Answer (score 13):

I implemented [my own version](https://github.com/moserware/SecretSplitter) of it that also uses PGP encryption. I describe the math behind it and give examples on how to use it in my blog post "[Life, Death, and Splitting Secrets](http://www.moserware.com/2011/11/life-death-and-splitting-secrets.html)".

**UPDATE:** It's now available as a [NuGet package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Moserware.SecretSplitter/) (as well as a detailed [example package](http://www.nuget.org/packages/Moserware.SecretSplitter.Sample/))

Answer (score 0):

Why not use ILDASM or Reflector to get the source from the application you have?

Comment: And then, what?  Steal the source (illegal)?  Reimplement it (a ton of work)?